# Remove zeros from Dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a DataFrame:

| index | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [0,1,2,0,4] |
| 1 | [1,0,2,0,0,1,7] |

I want to count the non zero values of each list for each row. Result:

| index | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_nonzero_elements_of_list(x):
    return len([x if x != 0])

df['B'].apply(count_nonzero_elements_of_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

By using numpy's `count_nonzero` method:

```
import numpy as np

df['B'] = [np.count_nonzero(x) for x in df['B'].tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

using numpy :

```
df['C'] = df.B.apply(np.count_nonzero)
```

output:

```
>>>
                       B  C
0        [0, 1, 2, 0, 4]  3
1  [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 7]  4
```